# MPEG2TS Multiplexer

Tags: mpeg2-ts

I am working in a streaming project which uses `MPEG2TS` protocol, Currently I am facing problem in audio video synchronization.

I am using PCR calculation as

```
PCR_base = (system_clock_frequency * PTS(audio/video)  ) /300

PCR_ext = (system_clock_frequency * PTS(audio/video)  ) % 300
```

and emiting `PCR` at every `100ms`

I am using `PTS` value as

```
PTS= (Encoded_time_stamp * 9 / 100 ) / 300
```

I am getting a av sync delay of `-150ms(video ahead of audio)` in mplayer and in VLC player I am getting only the First frame of video.

Please help me with the `PCR` calculation for muxing and also how to get the audio video synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The `PCR` is a clock you generate when you multiplex your stream so they can be synchronized at the demux step.

My guess is that your error is more likely to come from the `PTS`/`DTS` which are timestamps giving the moment when the decoder has to present/decode the A/V frames. It seems that your audio timestamps are a little bit late.

With no guarantee, have you tried to tweak it ?

```
audio_pts += 150; // in ms
```

Otherwise, you can use software tools to resynch your stream, like `ffmpeg` : have a llok at this good [tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html).
Also some related S.O. posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286076/3194340
- [Generate PCR from PTS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6199940/3194340)